# ошибка при передаче JSON ответа в Java объект с помощью Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Так я и пытаюсь понять как правильно мапить JSON на объект. То что на скриншоте видите - это и есть мапинг JSON c Java объектом ( как я думал). Делал по аналогии mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json . Мне казалось , если я запущу main метод, то он передаст в переменную citylist результат json ответа. Объект Citylist просто POJO объект. Мне бы понять о чем ошибка говорит.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу ответ JSON через GET запрос (URL)  передать в объект Java

**ВОТ КОД:**

```
import java.net.URL;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://someURL");

            // JSON file to Java object
            CityList citylist = mapper.readValue(url, CityList.class);



            // compact print
            System.out.println(citylist);




        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Простой POJO объект CityList:

```
   package model;

    import java.util.Map;

    public class CityList {

    private Map<String,String>plus_code;

    public Map<String, String> getPlus_code() {
        return plus_code;
    }

    public void setPlus_code(Map<String, String> plus_code) {
        this.plus_code = plus_code;
    }



    }
```

Вот ответ JSON , пример:

```
{
   "plus_code" : {
      "compound_code" : "P27Q+MC New York, NY, USA",
      "global_code" : "87G8P27Q+MC"
   }

}
```

Comment: Не хватает информации, покажите код контроллера(если это контроллер) и как мапите json на объект

Comment: Так я и пытаюсь понять как правильно мапить JSON на объект. То что на скриншоте видите - это и есть мапинг JSON  c Java объектом ( как я думал).  Делал по аналогии  https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/ .  Мне казалось , если я запущу main метод, то он передаст  в  переменную citylist результат json  ответа.   Объект Citylist просто POJO объект.   Мне бы понять о чем ошибка говорит.

Comment: код желательно приложить в виде текста, и добавить инфу из коммента в вопрос, чтобы люди по комментам не искали)

Comment: Прикрепите к ответу пример json и вашего объекта, а также часть с кодом мапингом

Comment: прикрепил, можете смотреть

Comment: Я пару лишних строк убрал , которые на скриншоте были

Comment: Стёпа, есть варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Представил ваш json пример в виде объекта

```
public class CityList {
    @JsonProperty("plus_code")
    private PlusCode plusCode;

    public PlusCode getPlusCode() {
        return plusCode;
    }

    public void setPlusCode(PlusCode plusCode) {
        this.plusCode = plusCode;
    }

    public class PlusCode {
        @JsonProperty("compound_code")
        private String compoundCode;

        @JsonProperty("global_code")
        private String globalCode;

        public String getCompoundCode() {
            return compoundCode;
        }

        public void setCompoundCode(String compoundCode) {
            this.compoundCode = compoundCode;
        }

        public String getGlobalCode() {
            return globalCode;
        }

        public void setGlobalCode(String globalCode) {
            this.globalCode = globalCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Проверил

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{ \"plus_code\" : { \"compound_code\" : \"P27Q+MC New York, NY, USA\", \"global_code\" : \"87G8P27Q+MC\" } }";

        try {
//            URL url = new URL("");

            // JSON file to Java object
            CityList citylist = mapper.readValue(json, CityList.class);

            // compact print
            System.out.println(citylist.getPlusCode().getCompoundCode() + " " + citylist.getPlusCode().getGlobalCode());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

И получил необходимый результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте ссылку, откуда берете данные, нужно понимать что из нее приходит.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, внимание и уделенное  время. Только мне все это необходимо понять в следующем контексте:  например  в этом примере вы сами инициилизировали  объект String json; , а мне нужно чтобы объект инициилизировался  через Spring boot rest  с помощью get запроса.Проще  говоря у меня есть ссылка которая возвращает json ответ и мне нужно понять как мне захватить этот ответ и передать в объект (например в тот же String json; ?  А дальше с помощью вашего примера я сделаю все что нужно .

Comment: Если быть совсем конкретным,то речь идет  о google maps geocoding api. Есть ссылка  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"  , которая возвращает  простой json ответ  с атрибутами. Далее мой вопрос выше все объяснит.Ссылка не точная , а примерная (потому что я не хочу светить свой ключ)  Ссылка не точная , а примерная (потому что я не хочу светить свой ключ)

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan >> `с помощью get запроса`. Get запрос только URL, или в тело запроса тоже что-то кладете?

Comment: Объясню насколько можно подробно:  1)  Есть ссылка условная https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY  , она возвращает данные о местоположении в зависимости от  атрибута  latlng  в теле запроса. 2)  Данные возвращаются в виде простого JSON 3) Мне нужно сделать такой get запрос на основе этой ссылки, чтобы  запарсить данные JSON в объект java , обработать их с базой данных и вернуть так же снова в JSON формате .  Т.е. мне нужно,чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку мне возвращались обработанные данные , а не первичные данные.

Comment: И самое главное мне нужно это сделать используя технологию SpringBoot Rest

Comment: Ну то как вы будете обрабатывать это у себя и отдавать через свой контроллер - это обсуждение уже не этого топика. У вас сейчас в чем именно затык? @VaagnAkopyan

Comment: Отвечаю, затык в том как данные json ,  которые поступают при запросе (GET) передать в объект String ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103704/discussion-between-dmtr-and-vaagn-akopyan).